# Cannot See Published Messages on RabbitMQ Dashboard After Publish Event

Tags: docker, rabbitmq, .net-5, masstransit

I run RabbitMQ through Docker Desktop with the following settings:

```
rabbitmq:
container_name: rabbitmq
restart: always
ports:
  - "5672:5672"
  - "15672:15672"
```

Second port number is for the RabbitMQ Dashboard. And, I have a basic REST API endpoint which is supposed to publish a RabbitMQ message as follows:

```
    private readonly IMediator _mediator;
    private readonly IPublishEndpoint _publish;

    public FlightController(IMediator mediator, IPublishEndpoint publish)
    {
        _mediator = mediator;
        _publish = publish;
    }

    [HttpPost(Name = "CheckoutCrew")]
    [ProducesResponseType((int)HttpStatusCode.Accepted)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> CheckoutCrew([FromBody] ScheduleFlightCommand command)
    {            
        var crewIds = new List<string>() { command.SeniorCrewId, command.Crew1Id, command.Crew2Id, command.Crew3Id };
        var hasSchedule = true;

        var crewCheckoutEvent = new CrewCheckoutEvent() { EmployeeNumbers = crewIds, HasSchedule = hasSchedule };

        await _publish.Publish(crewCheckoutEvent);

        return Accepted();
    }
```

And, below codes represent the configurations regarding RabbitMQ:

```
        services.AddMassTransit(config => {
            config.UsingRabbitMq((ctx, cfg) => {
                cfg.Host(Configuration["EventBusSettings:HostAddress"]);
                cfg.UseHealthCheck(ctx);
            });
        });

        services.AddMassTransitHostedService();
```

This `Configuration["EventBusSettings:HostAddress"]` line points here on `appsettings.json`:

```
"EventBusSettings": {
    "HostAddress": "amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672"
}
```

After I have run my API (named Flight.API), I check RabbitMQ logs via DockerDesktop and see these:

```
2022-03-31 12:52:41.794701+00:00 [info] <0.1020.0> accepting AMQP connection <0.1020.0> (xxx.xx.x.x:45292 -> xxx.xx.x.x:5672)

2022-03-31 12:52:41.817563+00:00 [info] <0.1020.0> Connection <0.1020.0> (xxx.xx.x.x:45292 -> xxx.xx.x.x:5672) has a client-provided name: Flight.API

2022-03-31 12:52:41.820704+00:00 [info] <0.1020.0> connection <0.1020.0> (xxx.xx.x.x:45292 -> xxx.xx.x.x:5672 - Flight.API): user 'guest' authenticated and granted access to vhost '/'
```

Everything seems okay, do not they?

I have also wrap `.Publish` method with `try...catch` but it also doesn't throw any exceptions. When my endpoint returns `Accepted` without any issue, I go and check RabbitMQ dashboard but it shows `Connections: 0`, `Channels: 0` etc. Message rates section is also staying on idle.

I cannot see what I am missing.

(Currently, I do not have any consumers, but I should still see some *life signs*, am I right? Those Connections and Channels counters shouldn't be staying at 0 after I have successfully published my payload)

Thank you in advance.

**Edit after adding a consumer class**

Still no changes on RabbitMQ Management screens. Everything is on their default values, empty, or idle. Below is my configuration on the consumer project:

```
        services.AddMassTransit(config => {
            config.AddConsumer<CrewChecoutConsumer>();
            config.UsingRabbitMq((ctx, cfg) => {
                cfg.Host(Configuration["EventBusSettings:HostAddress"]);
                cfg.UseHealthCheck(ctx);
                cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(EventBusConstants.CrewCheckoutQueue, config => {
                    config.ConfigureConsumer<CrewChecoutConsumer>(ctx);
                });
            });
        });

        services.AddMassTransitHostedService();

        services.AddScoped<CrewChecoutConsumer>();
```

`appsettings.json` file on consumer project is changed accordingly:

```
"EventBusSettings": {
    "HostAddress": "amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672"
}
```

And, below is my complete consumer class:

```
public class CrewChecoutConsumer : IConsumer<CrewCheckoutEvent>
{
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;
    private readonly IMediator _mediator;

    public CrewChecoutConsumer(IMapper mapper, IMediator mediator)
    {
        _mapper = mapper;
        _mediator = mediator;
    }

    public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<CrewCheckoutEvent> context)
    {
        foreach (var employeeNumber in context.Message.EmployeeNumbers)
        {
            var query = new GetSingleCrewQuery(employeeNumber);

            var crew = await _mediator.Send(query);

            crew.HasSchedule = context.Message.HasSchedule;

            var updateCrewCommand = new UpdateCrewCommand();

            _mapper.Map(crew, updateCrewCommand, typeof(CrewModel), typeof(UpdateCrewCommand));

            var result = await _mediator.Send(updateCrewCommand);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have any consumers, the only thing you will see is a message rate on the published message exchange as messages are delivered to the exchange, but then discarded as there are no receive endpoints (queues) bound to that message type exchange.

Until you have a consumer, you won't see any messages in any queues.

> Also, you should pass the controller's `CancellationToken` to the `Publish` call.

Comment: So, my problem is that I don't have any consumers? I'm confused as I'm new to MassTransit, but the tutor I have watched has a different RabbitMQ Dashboard outline after he has published his message. And, like me, he hasn't got any consumers at that point too. But, his Message Rates graph goes up (and immediately down as no consumers around probably?), his channels and connections counters are not indicating zeros

Comment: Add a message consumer, and you'll see the message.

Comment: Chris hello again, I have added a consumer. I have traced the whole process through debuging, and saw that code successfully arrives to consumer class and done things (a basic update on an entity) smoothly. So, configurations and other RabbitMQ settings should be OK, but still no changes on Management screen. Everything on Management screen is just empty or idle.. I read topics that if another local RabbitMQ version is running at the same time with the Docker version, Management screen might messed up, but I do not have another on premise RabbitMQ. I think I'm gonna pass this for now..